# Jahia CMS: Deleted pages from the site are added back after an updated template is deployed

Tags: content-management-system

Jahia CMS:

We are keeping default pages in the template, and these pages are created when we create a website using the template.

Now go to edit mode of the site, and delete a page from the site, and publish it.

Change something in template and deploy the new template again.

You will see the deleted page has reappeared for the edit mode, not for the published mode. Published mode is untouched.

Is it an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the expected behavior. 
What you mention as published mode is called "live mode". Creation of content has to be published before being available in live mode.
Only change made in templates does not have to be published.